# MVC Chart Helper C# ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, auto-update

I have a database in my MVC 3 application and am trying to make a chart from it. The documentation for how to create a chart from a database table is not thorough enough and am stuck. I've searched extensively online but everyone is using pre-defined static input for their charts. I want a chart that updates as soon as its controller changes the data.

Here is my code so far:
What am I missing?

```
    // Get: /Students/ShowData
    public ActionResult ShowData()
    {
        var key = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
       .AddSeries(chartType: "bar")
           .DataBindTable(b.Students.ToList())
       .Write();
        return null;
    }
```

If I do this:

```
// Get: /Students/ShowData
public ActionResult ShowData()
{
    Grade grade1 = db.Students.Find(1);
    var key = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
   .AddSeries(
       chartType: "bar",
       xValue: new[] { grade1.Name, "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May" },
       yValues: new[] { grade1.Grade.ToString() , "20", "40", "10", "10" })
       .DataBindTable(b.Students.ToList())
   .Write();
    return null;
}
```

I can see the name of the first student in the table...is there a way to go about showing all the student and their grades?

Comment: Is this java (or) C#?

Comment: Never mind people. I got it. This is C# and the answer is to use the ToList() method with chartType COLUMN not bar!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Grade grade = new Grade();    
List<Grade> listGrade = new List<Grade>();
listGrade = grade.getData(); // getData(); return List of all student
List<String> nameList = new List<String>();
List<String> gradeList = new List<String>();
foreach(var item in listGrade)
{
nameList.Add(item.Name);
gradeList.Add(item.Grade);
}
IEnumerable<String> resultListName = nameList.ToList();
IEnumerable<String> resultListGrade = gradeList.ToList();
var key = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
   .AddSeries(
       chartType: "bar",
       xValue: resultListName},
       yValues: resultListGrade)
       .DataBindTable(b.Students.ToList())
   .Write();
    return null;
```